# How to convert json to Vector ? ClassCastException gson Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, vector, gson

I have a problem to read json and convert it to Vector of objects, The weird part is this issue occurs only on Android 4.4.2 Device , and on emulator it's working.

Here is my code:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(string));

AllConversationsObject allConversationsObject = gson.fromJson(reader,AllConversationsObject.class);

allConversationObject.conversations.get(0)
```

Here is AllConversationsObject:

```
public class AllConversationsObject  {
    Vector<Conversation>  conversations;
    String bookmark;

    public Vector<Conversation> getConversations() {
        return conversations;
    }

    public void setConversations(Vector<Conversation> conversations) {
        this.conversations = conversations;
    }

    public String getBookmark() {
        return bookmark;
    }

    public void setBookmark(String bookmark) {
        this.bookmark = bookmark;
    }
}
```

The application crash on `conversations.get(0)` with this error:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to
>   com.myapp.com.Conversation

Here is build.gradle :

> ```
> compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
> ```

Here is the Json:

```
{
  "bookmark": "string",
  "conversations": [
    {},
    {}
  ]
}
```

what's the problem ? Thank you

Comment: without sample json it's impossible to answer... also why Vector not ArrayList ?

Comment: @Selvin Thank you, I can use ArrayList, but is there a problem with Vector ? I will add the json, but I am 100% sure there is no problem with Json since it's working on other versions

Comment: What is your **reader**? Is you a string, how do you create it?

Comment: @RoShanShan I've edited the question. Thank you

Comment: I believe that your `AllConversationsObject.conversations` type becomes simply `Vector` rather than `Vector<Conversation>` -- probably after byte-code post-processing with tools like ProGuard. By default, Gson, if having no enough type info, deserializes JSON objects as `LinkedTreeMap`. So that's why you can't cast the vector elements. You have to inspect the _real_ field type with `AllConversationsObject.class.getDeclaredField("conversations").getGenericType()` and ensure it results as java.util.Vector<....Conversation>` and not `class java.util.Vector`.

Comment: Please post the `Conversation` object structure as well.

Comment: Replace `JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(string));` by `JsonReader reader = new Gson().toJson(string) `and try again

Comment: Another note is that `allConversationObject.conversations.get(0)` cannot fail alone because there is _no_ real type cast. You seem trying to cast `allConversationObject.conversations.get(0)` to a `Conversation` object per se: `Conversation conversation = allConversationObject.conversations.get(0);` or whatever similar to this -- this where it can happen. No other scenarios are possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Vector` use `List` but my concern is in the `bookmark` field.

According to the `json` it is an **array** of some objects, but you are modeling it as a `String`. You should declare it as `List<Object>` or any `List<String>` if you are sure that `bookmark` is array of `String`

Comment: Thank you, the book mark is string, I've edited my question. sorry ! I will check that and let you know. Thanks again

Comment: Could you please explain, why I need to use List instead of Vector ?

Comment: List has better performence due to Vector is synchronized

Comment: Thank you, It works , but it seems this is a bug in gson, since it's not a performance issue, Thanks again